# Calculate a specified function with the help of a series function c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, formula, series, pow

[image: Here is the function and series]

The function f(x) and the series need to end up with the same answer
This is my attempt on this task, but it gives me different results and I don't fully understand the concept of series in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x, y1, y2, a;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter x: ";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Enter n: ";
    cin>>n;
    if (x == 0) x = 3.0;
    y1 = 1.0/(2.0*x+5.0);
    a = 1.0/11;
    y2 = a;
    cout<<"f(x) = "<<y1<<endl;
    if(x > -5.0/2.0 && x < 17.0/2.0){
        for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++){
            a = (a*(-1)*pow(2.0/11.0,k))/pow(11.0,k);
            y2 = y2 + a;
        }
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }

    cout<<"Sum = "<<y2<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I used any x from -2,5 to 8,5 and n up to 100
the results are always different...
the function and sum of the series are supposed to have very close, if not equal answers, but it's not in my case..

How am I supposed to do it? would be happy for an explanation)

Comment: "Does not work" is not a helpful description.

Comment: What values did you use for `x` and `n`? What results did you get? How is that wrong? Oh, and you do your calculations using `double` values but store them in `float`s. That alone causes rounding problems.

Comment: The terms in the summation you linked to are almost completely unlike your terms.

Comment: I'm not very good at math , and dont fully unserstand how to do this properly,

Comment: One problem here `(a*(-1)*pow(2.0/11.0,k))/pow(11.0,k);` is that you multiply `a` by a very small number and then divide it by a very large number. That makes it quickly get small enough not to be noticed when adding it to `y2`. So the value of `n` doesn't matter much. BTW, where did the last `pow` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just use the correct term for your sum:

```
a = pow(-2.0 / 11.0 * (x - 3), k) / 11.0;
```

Note that I combined the terms in the power. The division by `11` may also be moved to the end, saving some operations. But then you would need a different initialization. However, this would also allow you to calculate `a` incrementally. Something like this:

```
//Initialization
a = 1.0;
y2 = a;
double factor = -2.0 / 11.0 * (x - 3);
//...

for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++) 
{
    a *= factor;
    y2 += a;
}

//Finally
cout << "Sum = " << y2 / 11.0f << endl;
```